# What is the alternate to 443 port?

Tags: c#, iis, ssl, https

I have a developed a web application using c#.net and deployed this on IIS .Our requirement is to make it available only on https. So I have to test it on https.

But in my windows 8 machine with IIS 8 I can't select 443 port because it says it is used by another process WWAHost.exe and it is a process of windows 8 metro application service.

Is there a way I can take this port 443 from that service ?

Comment: This is more of a system administration question that programming, so it may get migrated to serverfault.com. Check the IIS documentation to see if there's a way to disable its default HTTPS service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is necessary -- you can use any available port you want in IIS for secure connections (especially for testing purposes).  However, you must have a certificate installed.  And because browsers use port 443 as their default when serving up https requests, you'll have to manually supply the port you assign in your url.

Look at DataBindings when setting up the site in IIS.  You'll want to choose HTTPS.  Then when accessing via the browser:

> https://yourdomain.com:12345 (assuming port 12345 is what you assigned
>   it)

Good luck.